# How to count unique items based on column?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the counts of unique items in a csv column using Python.

I have number of CSV files. Each CSV file contains of 5 columns (without header):

```
'AB', 'asd', 'asd2', 'asd3', 'asd4'
'AB', 'asd', 'asd2', 'asd3', 'asd4'
'AB', 'poi', 'poi2', 'poi3', 'poi4'
'BG', 'put', 'put2', 'put3', 'put4'
'BG', 'asd', 'asd2', 'asd3', 'asd4'
'BG', 'poi', 'poi2', 'poi3', 'poi4'
```

What I want is to take first two columns from each file

```
'AB', 'asd'
'AB', 'asd'
'AB', 'poi'
'BG', 'put'
'BG', 'asd'
'BG', 'poi'
```

And then do a count of column 2 unique items based on 1 column. So the result should look:

```
'AB': 2   # AB has unique values 'asd' and 'poi'
'BG': 3   # BG has unique vales 'put', 'asd' and 'poi'
```

Comment: Is it Python 3 or 2? You should only add the tag that is relevant to your question, not both of them if they dont' matter for this question.

Comment: Both versions are fine.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: your question has badformatting as well - you can see this easily by observing the black / red coloring..

Comment: Which version you're using could very will affect how the csv file needs to be handled, so saying "both" potentially makes your question more difficult to answer.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, thanks, I've made changes accordingly. I hope it looks good now.

Comment: @martineau, thanks, I made corrections accordingly.

Comment: You still have no [mcve] of what you tried, you still have no specific question related to code you produced that does not work. You still ask a "Here is my problem, solve it for me" question - which are generally to broad to be answered here. Please [edit] and show what you tried to solve this. You might want to research the `module csv` for reading and `dict` or `itertools.groupby` or `collections.defaultdict` if you want to use no pandas to do the grouping.

Comment: @John Johnson: Read the the rows of the files using the `csv` module. For Python 2 use `open(filename, 'rb')`. For each file, create a dictionary mapping whose keys are values from the first column to an associated `set` comprised of values seen from the second column. When done, the number of members of each of these `set`s will tell you the number of unique values that seen with values in the corresponding  first column.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third-party libs, then one good option is to use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

This will give you a `pandas.DataFrame`, on which you can select the columns that you want and then use [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

This could look like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(...)     # specify 'filename', 'delimiter' and other info
print(df)
print(df['col_name'].value_counts())    # 'col_name' depends on how you opened the file
```